# how do I set widescreen 16:9 lubuntu on virtualbox windows 8 host?

Tags: virtualbox

I use the just realesed VirtuBox 4.3.20 on a Windows 8 64-bit. Guest additions installed. I just installed the last version of lubuntu but I can't set the widescreen resolution. In the monitor settings the 1600x900 resolution is not present, and I tried to do as some guides say through the terminal but I didn't find out a solution.